# Fluid dynamics' equivalent to current smoothing

Tags: fluid-mechanics

Is there an arrangement of components the takes a source of gas with oscillating pressure and outputs a steady near constant pressure stream?

Comment: A silencer such as fitted to a car exhaust...

Comment: Compressed air receiver tanks.

Comment: Outside of the acoustic response frequencies, there are pressure regulators for different gasses that supply a constant pressure from a higher pressure source. The pressure drop can be fairly small.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem in the field of *noise control* (within the larger field of *engineering acoustics*). Do you have access to any of the standard textbooks on engineering acoustics? You'll most likely find your answer there.

Also please note that there is a device called a *noise suppressor* or *muffler* which is commonly used to eliminate or minimize the generation and propagation of noise from a pressurized air outlet. If you search on these terms you will uncover the websites of the firms that design and sell them, and find out how to solve your problem.
.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a few bypass pipes with a constraint such as a fin or a stator or a positive blocking valve, spring loaded, that will intake the tip of pressure surge amplitude and deliver it muted farther down the stream.

A comparable liquid regulator would be one with a slanted ramp skimming the flow at the average volume and merging it back down stream.